# ElasticSearch + Twitter river class not found

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to install twitter river plugin on elastic search. I have done it before on my mac without any issues, but this time I am trying to install on a Linux server and I keep getting this class not found exception. The exception comes when I use curl -XPUT command as shown in https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-twitter/blob/master/README.md

Here's the exception I get :-

```
[2013-11-25 15:12:00,116][WARN ][river                    ] [Fasaud] failed to create                 river [twitter][my_twitter_river2]
org.elasticsearch.common.settings.NoClassSettingsException: Failed to load class with value [twitter]
    at org.elasticsearch.river.RiverModule.loadTypeModule(RiverModule.java:87)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.RiverModule.spawnModules(RiverModule.java:58)
at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.add(ModulesBuilder.java:44)
at org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService.createRiver(RiversService.java:135)
at org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService$ApplyRivers$2.onResponse(RiversService.java:271)
at org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService$ApplyRivers$2.onResponse(RiversService.java:265)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$ThreadedActionListener$1.run(TransportAction.java:93)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.elasticsearch.river.RiverModule.loadTypeModule(RiverModule.java:73)
... 9 more
```

I have tried restarting, installing many many times and can't get it to work anyhow. I can also see that the jar files present in the plugin directories contain the class twitter but for some reason they're not available to elasticsearch execution.

Comment: Did you install it on all the nodes, or only the one?

Comment: I have only one node, I am running it on a single machine.

Comment: ES has permission to the plugins folder, and the plugins themselves? And you haven't changed where ES should look for plugins?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 25 14:21 river-twitter
    60K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  55K Nov 25 14:21 twitter4j-stream-3.0.3.jar
    284K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 278K Nov 25 14:21 twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar
     20K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18K Nov 25 14:21 elasticsearch-river-twitter-1.4.0.jar

Comment: How do I check if it has permissions and also where does it look for plugins. I haven't changed it for sure.

Comment: `ls -l /path/to/dir` Default install is usually /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins so it would be `ls -l /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins`

Comment: Based on the above comment, it looks like it was installed as root. How did you install elasticsearch? Do you know if elasticsearch runs as user elasticsearch and group elasticsearch, or is it running as root? Was it through a deb package on a system that uses debian as a package manager (such as ubuntu) or .rpm (centos, fedora) by downloading recently from elasticsearch.org?

Comment: I am currently using root user, thats why it got installed as root. I tried both versions using a .deb package and manually downloading .tar.gz file.

Comment: I also checked, elastic search in running as root.

Comment: ok, in elasticsearch/plugins you have a folder called  river-twitter right? Where are the .jar files located? are they in elasticsearch/plugins are in elasticsearch/plugins/river-twitter

Comment: In river-twitter :-                                                   ~/elasticsearch-0.90.7# ls -l plugins/river-twitter/
total 364
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18139 Nov 25 14:21 elasticsearch-river-twitter-1.4.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 284077 Nov 25 14:21 twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  56307 Nov 25 14:21 twitter4j-stream-3.0.3.jar

Comment: Actually I read that wrong, check to see which elasticsearch install you are running. Do `ps aux|grep elasticsearch` and that will tell which executable is running on that machine (look for a line that looks like this: (`-Des.default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch`)

Comment: Hey, it worked. I realised I was running two many elastic search instances at the same time. For some reason that was causing the problem. I killed all the existing instances and started a new one from the /usr/share/elasticsearch directory and it worked fine. Great, thanks for your help, Immensely appreciated.

Comment: I took these steps and put them in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a configuration and install issue.

Steps:

1. Check to see where elasticsearch is installed by running `ps aux|grep elasticsearch` (on linux) and that will tell which executable is running on that machine (look for a line that looks like this: (-Des.default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch) or something similar.
2. If several elasticsearch instances running, kill them all and start the one you care about.
3. Ensure that only one instance of elasticsearch is running (if that is the intent) and, from step one above, go to the home path directory.
4. Ensure that the plugin is installed in this directory in elasticsearch/plugins dir.

Restart elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

confirm your classpath contain a text file es-plugin.properties with content

plugin=your.package.YourRiverPlugin

missing of such a property file shows almost the same error.

for more info, please refer http://blog.trifork.com/2013/01/10/how-to-write-an-elasticsearch-river-plugin/