# Writing a custom river

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm making my first go at writing a river. ([Here's the source code](https://bitbucket.org/futurechan/example-river/src))

I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.trifork.com/2013/01/10/how-to-write-an-elasticsearch-river-plugin/) and compared it to [this existing river](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc), but I haven't had much luck.

To deploy the river, I created a folder called `example-river`, dropped my jar in that folder, and restarted the node. Everything starts up fine.

I have also tried `bin/plugin --url file:///path/to/plugin --install example-river`, which seems to work, but it unpacks my jar.

When I issue this PUT request:

```
http://localhost:9200/_river/example_river/_meta
{
    "type": "example_river",
  "example_river":{
    "blah":"blah"
  }
}
```

I get this exception:

> [2014-04-20 22:28:46,538][DEBUG][river                    ] [Gloom]
>   creating river [example_river][example_river] [2014-04-20
>   22:28:46,543][WARN ][river                    ] [Gloom] failed to
>   create river [example_river][example_river]
>   org.elasticsearch.common.settings.NoClassSettingsException: Failed to
>   load class with value [example_river]     at
>   org.elasticsearch.river.RiverModule.loadTypeModule(RiverModule.java:87)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.river.RiverModule.spawnModules(RiverModule.java:58)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.add(ModulesBuilder.java:44)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService.createRiver(RiversService.java:137)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService$ApplyRivers$2.onResponse(RiversService.java:275)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService$ApplyRivers$2.onResponse(RiversService.java:269)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$ThreadedActionListener$1.run(TransportAction.java:93)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example_river   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.elasticsearch.river.RiverModule.loadTypeModule(RiverModule.java:73)
>     ... 9 more

Can someone point out what I am missing?

Comment: Can you find your river jar in elasticsearch plugin folder???

Comment: @BlackPOP Yes, because I dropped it in the folder manually.

Comment: Have you find any logs that says that your plugin loaded during ES startup like                                                    [2014-04-21 16:51:15,239][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Bennet du Paris] loaded [mongodb-river, mapper-attachments], sites [river-mongodb]
[2014-04-21 16:51:18,649][INFO ][node                     ] [Bennet du Paris] initialized
[2014-04-21 16:51:18,650][INFO ][node                     ] [Bennet du Paris] starting ...

Comment: @BlackPOP No, I don't see any log statement like that.

Comment: @BlackPOP, did you take a look at the project I posted? I wonder if it works for anyone else.

Comment: May I I know for which version u wrote d plug in??

Comment: @BlackPOP Java version 1.7. I'm deploying to ES 1.1

Comment: @BlackPOP, did you take a look at the project I posted? I wonder if it works for anyone else.

Comment: Sorry i coundn't use it..!

Comment: @BlackPOP what was wrong with it? Did it not compile?

Comment: I got d same error tat u got...

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196093/elasticsearch-twitter-river-class-not-found?